# Почему построчное считывание очень большого csv файла может завершиться ошибкой?

Tags: c#, csv

Если у мне нужно считать csv файл на миллионы строк, разве StreamReader и метод ReadLine в цикле не будут хранить в памяти только текущую строку и текущее смещение строки от ее начала? Откуда тогда может быть ошибка из-за потребления памяти?

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.csv")) {
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var s = sr.ReadLine();
        // Запись в БД
    }
}
```

Comment: Включите, пожалуйста, код в вопрос

Comment: Ошибка какая возникает? Покажите код полностью.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не так понял суть проблемы. OutOfMemory возникает если строка слишком длинная.

Comment: А если не делать запись в БД, т.е.  только ReadLine() в цикле, ошибка возникает?

Comment: Да, просто очень большая CSV

Comment: Такая большая строка, что она в память не лезет? Сколько же памяти и какая же строка? )